# ConvertTo-SecureString - use encrypted password for everyone

Tags: powershell, encryption

I stored a pw encrypted in a txt file and load it into a powershell session with:

`gc .\localadmincred.txt | convertto-securestring`

This doesn't work because i read that only the User that encrypted that key, can convert it to a secure string, everyone als can't decrypt the string that is in my txt.

How can I store an encrypted string in a file so that everyone can use it with `convertto-securestring`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If an user can convert the credentials as a securestring, it is trivially decrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encrypt the string with a key. If another user has the key, he/she will be able to decrypt the string.

See example: [Secure Password with PowerShell: Encrypting Credentials – Part 2](http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/)

Comment: thank you, that worked. I don't really get why a key like this `[Byte[]]$key = (1..16)` solves this issue, but it works :)

Comment: @SimonS Because **that's the key that is used to encrypt the SecureString**. By embedding it in the script, **anyone reading the source can decrypt the password**.